# Difference between a class and its instance

Tags: ruby

How does Ruby internally differentiate between a class and its instance like `MyClass` and `obj` below? What does it do to allow creation of instances of `MyClass` but not of `obj`?

```
MyClass = Class.new
obj = MyClass.new
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn’t differentiate. `MyClass` is an instance of [`Class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html) (in the same way that `obj` is an instance of `MyClass`), which implements the [`new` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-i-new), and [`Object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html) does not. It’s pretty much that simple—there’s nothing especially extraordinary happening here, `Class#new` is much like any other method.

Here we can see the ancestry of each object’s class:

```
MyClass = Class.new
obj = MyClass.new

MyClass.class.ancestors  #=> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
obj.class.ancestors      #=> [MyClass, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Comment: ok. but how does it differentiate between MyClass(instance of Class) and obj(instance of MyClass)?

Comment: @surase.prasad That’s it: one is an instance of `Class`, and the other is not. There’s no special differentiation.

Comment: usually, we are taught that classes and objects are different but ruby break it by saying that everything is an object. so some objects are classes(through user's view) and some objects are objects(like obj in the question). i want to kwn that how does ruby internally differentiate between classes(String, fixnum, MyClass) and objects(obj, "prasad")

Comment: @surase.prasad My point is that it doesn’t differentiate. “Some objects are objects”—no, *all* objects are objects. A class is an object too: `Class.new.ancestors.include? Object #=> true`. A class is an instance of Class the same way an object is an instance of some other class (e.g. MyClass).